# Using clang 3.1 with initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

When I compile this code:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
  std::vector<T> v;
  S(initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
    std::cout << "constructed with a " << l.size() << "-element list\n";
  }
};
```

using the following command line:

```
 clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ initializer_list.cpp
```

I get the following error.

```
initializer_list.cpp:12:23: error: expected ')'
    S(initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
```

Does anyone know the fix if any??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list ?

Comment: Yes. It was from that example.

Comment: Please don't format your code manually with HTML. See [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to format code here. I did it for you this time.

Comment: I ended up installing g++ 4.7.0 and it compiles without a hitch, so I guess I'll have to wait for clang++ to be updated. I've waited a long time for C++ to become a "modern" programming language with c++11. I guess can wait a little longer for all the tools to work. And then a little longer for "concepts"

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to write `std::initializer_list<T>`.  Make sure you include `<initializer_list>`.

Comment: I do have <initializer_list> included and it gives the same error with or without std:: prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is incomplete. It would be useful if you can provide a complete example. The problem with the code as written is that you're missing

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

... and `initializer_list` is in namespace `std`, so you're also missing a `std::` from your constructor declaration.

However, since you've claimed that neither of these is the issue, the most likely cause would seem to be that your C++ standard library implementation doesn't provide `std::initializer_list`. That would be the case if Clang is using GCC's libstdc++, and you do not have a suitably new version of that installed: you need at least version 4.4, but note that [a patch](http://clang.llvm.org/libstdc++4.4-clang0x.patch) is required to fix bugs in libstdc++-4.4 in order to make it work with Clang in C++11 mode, otherwise you will get errors about `type_info` and various other problems.

Also, you say that the diagnostic you received is this:

```
initializer_list.cpp:12:23: error: expected ')'
    S(initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
                      ^
```

(I've reconstructed the caret from the provided column number; it would be useful to preserve it in future questions.) For any of the above explanations, this will not be the first diagnostic which Clang produces; that would be something along the lines of:

```
initializer_list.cpp:12:5: error: no template named 'initializer_list'; did you mean 'std::initializer_list'?
  S(initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    std::initializer_list
```

So either you've missed out the first diagnostic from your question, or the problem is that you have declared some *other* (non-`template`) type named `initializer_list` in the code you omitted in your question, and that is hiding `std::initializer_list`. Without seeing the rest of your code or the rest of your diagnostics, it's not possible to tell which.